# Finding PowerPoint slide number & slide title in VSTO

Tags: asp.net, vsto, powerpoint

I am writing a small plugin on ASP.NET C# VSTO and I want to be able to capture slide number and title of the slides when a slideshow is happening.

Can someone share sample code to capture title of the slide and slide number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow.Presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

Presentation pres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;

```
        foreach (Slide s in pres.Slides)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(s.SlideIndex);
        }
```

The Slide title I don't know, yet

Answer (score 0):

Capture event `SlideShowNextSlide` and from the `Wn` variable, get the slide's index/title. Here's a VBA example:

```
Private Sub app_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
Dim s As Slide
s = Wn.View.Slide
Dim slideTitle As String


If s.Layout <> ppLayoutBlank Then
    If s.Shapes.HasTitle Then
        slideTitle = s.Shapes.Title
    Else
        slideTitle = "(nothing)"
    End If
End If

Dim sIndex As Integer
sIndex = s.SlideIndex

End Sub
```